# Using the run function with a URL inside a variable

Tags: autohotkey

The Run function doesn't work as expected on a URL inside of a variable.

I'm trying to clean up a script I've written that makes shortcuts for different websites. To let chrome navigate to a specific website I would write for example:

```
Run, "https://google.com"
```

Which works.

I've tried however to write a function with parameters to make the script more efficient but it isn't working.

```
goToSite(site) {
 Run, site
}
goToSite("https://google.com")
```

Expected result: Chrome navigates to specified URL

Actual result: "The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In commands (Run, Send etc.) you have to enclose the variables in percent signs:

```
goToSite(site){
    Run, %site%
}
goToSite("https://google.com")
```

See
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s61